# Is it possible to set a repository on a specific storage?

Tags: artifactory

I am new to Artifactory and I am currently experiencing with its trial.

For a specific archiving case, I wonder if it is possible to associate some repositories to a specific storage?

I did not find any information about this neither in the web user interface nor in the Artifactory documentation.

Thank you,

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible, as it would break deduplication between repositories. Do you think this would be useful for any particular reason, or do you have a specific problem in mind that this would solve? Depending on your use case, there's usually a better solution available.

Comment: Yes, I would put some artifacts that will not be accessed a lot on less-effective but with a lower cost storages. The only way I found to set up this is to have two artifactory instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifactory support answered me that is currently not possible do this with only one Artifactory instance.